# Get 64bit ProgramFiles path running 32bit JVM

Tags: java

When running a jar file in a 32bit JVM **System.getenv("programfiles")** returns **C:\Program Files (x86)**.

Is there any way of getting the 64 bit version of program files regardless of what JVM you are running on?

Comment: Obvious question: if your OS is 64bit, why do you run a 32bit JVM?

Comment: @fge I am distributing this to other users which may (as I found out when looking at problems with this) have a 32 bit JRE associated with the .jar extension.

Comment: Did you check if there is another environment variable you can use?

Comment: What's in that environment variable when you run on a 64-bit JVM?

Comment: @chrylis System.getenv("programfiles") returns C:\Program Files on a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: The environment variable `ProgramW6432` is available for this purpose, and only turns up on 64bit windows. The question is to what purpose?